# I'm running raspbian on my pi 3 model b and trying to get the i2c TCS3472 colour sensor working

Tags: i2c, adafruit

I am trying to get the TCS3472 color sensor to work with RaspberryPi, I have setup I2C succesfully and can detect the sensor with i2cdetect -y 1
which outputs

```
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
 00: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 29 -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

```
ls /dev/i2*
```

gives 2 devices

```
/dev/i2c-1  /dev/i2c-2
```

If I test the connection with this.

```
import board
import adafruit_tcs34725
i2c = board.I2C()
sensor = adafruit_tcs34725.TCS34725(i2c)
```

I get a runtime error

```
 RuntimeError: Could not find sensor, check wiring!
```

The unit works with Ardiuno.

Using Python 3.9.2

Based on the CircuitPython module for the TCS34725 color sensor.
It is not an original AdaFruit product but I would definitely buy one if that was the problem

Comment: Check that the code is using the correct I2C bus.

Comment: I know that many AdaFruit CircuitPython packages do not run well in Rpi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the line producing the error in the adafruit_tcs34725.py library file and printed out the sensor ID and added it to the expected list (was 77 is 0x4D in hex)

```
        print(sensor_id)
        if sensor_id not in (0x44, 0x10, 0x4D):
            raise RuntimeError("Could not find sensor, check wiring!")
```

Hope this helps someone save a bit of time. I am the best.

Comment: It is not ideal making changes to a library file